# Value of $\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{1}{t^{2}\left(1+t^{2}\right)}\sin\left(\frac{1}{t}\sin\frac{1}{t}\right)e^{-\frac{1}{t^{2}}}$.

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis

I want to find the value of
$$\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{1}{t^{2}\left(1+t^{2}\right)}\sin\left(\frac{1}{t}\sin\frac{1}{t}\right)\exp\left({-\frac{1}{t^{2}}}\right).$$
Because the fraction term tends to $\infty$ and the exponential term tends to $0$, I cannot figure out which term is more dominant.

I tried WolframAlpha computation, but WolframAlpha could not figure out this limit as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limit is $0$ because $\sin x$ is bounded and $\lim t^{k} e^{-1/t^{2}}=0$ for any integer $k$. Here you can take  $k=-2$